# How can I get gmail to show me chat+rooms instead of hangouts?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I have 2 GSuite / Google Workspace accounts (different domains). When I log into gmail on one of them I see Chat + Rooms on the left gmail area

[image]

When I log into the other I still see hangouts

[image]

Is there a setting somewhere in either gmail or gsuites admin that will switch the 2nd gmail to show chat + rooms instead of hangouts?

Note: In the account showing Hangouts I see nothing in the admin panel under "Apps > Google Workspace > Settings for Google Chat and classic Hangouts" nor did I notice anything in "Apps > G Suite > Settings for Gmail" but maybe I missed it.

Comment: Have you already read [Get started: Chat setup guide for admins
> Set up Chat for your organization](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9269628?hl=en)?

Comment: Thanks. That was it! I find the Google admin console has a pretty poor UX. The first area shows "Status: On" and there is no indication that clicking there will bring up 6+ options instead of just "on/off".